# Why can I use private default constructor in decltype()?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, private-members, decltype

Look at the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class test
{
private:
    test() { }
public:
    test foo() { return *this; }

    static const char *name() { return "test"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << decltype(test().foo())::name() << std::endl;               // 1
    std::cout << decltype(std::declval<test>().foo())::name() << std::endl; // 2
}
```

I expected `// 1` line cannot be compiled because the default constructor of `test` is private.

[However, it works well.](http://ideone.com/AMdoez) I tested it on my g++ 4.8.3 with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` in disbelief, but it works well without any errors or warnings.

(In addition, it seems to work well in GCC 4.9.1 as well.)

From [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval), I guess we can use private default constructor if the expression is unevaluated. So, I tested the following to check it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class test
{
private:
    test(int) { }
public:
    test foo() { return *this; }

    static const char *name() { return "test"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << decltype(test().foo())::name() << std::endl;               // 1
    std::cout << decltype(std::declval<test>().foo())::name() << std::endl; // 2
}
```

[(live example)](http://ideone.com/JtbM2n)

As expected, it wasn't compiled.

But.... **why??** How can it be possible? Can we use **private** members in unevaluated expression? Or is there a special rule for default constructors? Could you explain me why?

Comment: Doesn't compile in clang.

Comment: @T.C. Oh really? then it may be just GCC's bug..

Comment: Um, C++98 has no `decltype`. Or `declval`. Of course it doesn't compile.

Comment: @T.C. Oh, my brain was screwed ;;

Comment: Hum, it's compiled in even GCC 4.9.1...

Comment: It seems like a g++ bug, clang doesn't compile, you can see here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bdd0af1734740d3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It shouldn't compile. C++11 [class.temporary] has this to say about creating a temporary object:

> 12.2/1 Even when the creation of the temporary object is **unevaluated**
>   or otherwise avoided, **all the semantic restrictions shall be respected** as if the temporary object had been created and later destroyed. [ *Note:* even if there is no call to the destructor or copy/move constructor, all the **semantic restrictions, such as accessibility** and whether the function is deleted, shall be satisfied. However, in the special case of a function call used as the operand of a *decltype-specifier*, no temporary is introduced, so the foregoing does not apply to the prvalue of any such function call. — *end note* ]

So, even when unevaluated, you're still restricted by the accessibility of any functions (including constructors) needed to create and destroy the temporary. The final sentence of the note clarifies that a function like `declval` can be used to avoid this obstacle.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for *the final sentence*. (oh, I see I can't accept an answer in one minute >o<)

Comment: Then it must be gcc's bug; should I report it? >o<

Comment: The end note shows: decltype-specifier, no temporary is introduced, so the foregoing does not apply to the prvalue of any such function call. 
How to understand this part?